# Kantorovich translocation of masses 1942 paper

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, linear-programming, optimal-transport

I would appreciate help understanding Kantorovich's 1942 paper on translocation on masses.

The English translation can be found here:
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Kantorovitch-translocation-of-masses-1942.pdf

I do not understand how he constructs the potential $U$ in the *Necessity 
of the Condition* part (p.3-4).
Is $x_0$ supposed to $\zeta_n$ instead of $\zeta_0$? What is $y_0$ in the chain? And why is the expression $U(y)=r(x_0,y_0)-r(x_n,y_n)$ independent of the choice of the chain?